# Mistake in Havdala- didn't drink Havdala cup

Tags: halacha, mistakes, havdalah

Someone made Havdala and forgot to drink the cup of wine. Did he and the listeners fulfill their obligation?

Answer (score 2):

[Mishnah Berurah 296 (2) [9]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=)  makes it a requirement to drink at least a mouthful of whatever drink he uses for havdalah and if he does not drink this quantity he has not fulfilled the mitzvah.